# Encoding an OData query as a URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, odata

I am trying to encode an odata query with various filter parameters in python. The plain string version of the request looks something like this:

```
*endpoint*?$filter=datecolumn gt 2019-01-01T00:00:00Z
```

In order to actually request data from the server, I need to format the string as a URL that I can pass in a request. The URL version looks like this:

```
*endpoint*?%24filter=datecolumn%20gt%'2019-01-01T00:00:00Z
```

To easily get the URL version of the string in python I originally tried using the urllib package:

```
import urllib
urllib.parse.quote('?$filter=datecolumn gt 2019-01-01T00:00:00Z')
```

but this seems to overformat the string. It replaces characters like the starting dollar sign and the equals sign with their url-encoded counterparts, which makes my odata query not work. Is there a method in python or any packages that can be used to easily encode string for odata queries?

Generally, is there a name for the type of encoding used by odata in the request?

Answer (score 0):

As "$" and "=" are the special characters (according to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2), we won't need to encode them. I'd say that you should encode the value ("datecolumn gt 2019-01-01T00:00:00Z") only.

Answer (score 0):

I had an interest in this lately and toyed with the infamous Northwind sample service, and while there are some python packages to try out, I thought first I'd see how far I could get with only requests and built-in python.

You can see that formatting the URL strings is as simple as Hoang HUA says - and I am not even using the 'full strength' of commands available with requests [Note: The table 'join' manipulations are happening on the client side and this brute force code is still very short]:

```
import requests
import operator

def make_HTTP_request(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.json()

srvc_root = 'https://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc'

order_date = '1998-01-01T00:00:00Z'
filter = '$filter=OrderDate gt {} and RequiredDate lt ShippedDate'.format(order_date)
orders_qry = '$select=OrderID,CustomerID,EmployeeID&{}'.format(filter)
url_orders_qry = '{}/Orders?{}'.format(srvc_root, orders_qry)
urldict_orders = make_HTTP_request(url_orders_qry)

customerIDs = []
employeeIDs = []

for order in urldict_orders['value']:
    customerIDs.append(order['CustomerID'])
    employeeIDs.append(str(order['EmployeeID']))

customer_qry = '$select={}&$filter=CustomerID eq \'{}\''.format('CustomerID,CompanyName', '\' or CustomerID eq \''.join(customerIDs))
url_customers_qry = '{}/Customers?{}'.format(srvc_root, customer_qry)
urldict_customers = make_HTTP_request(url_customers_qry)

employee_qry = '$select={}&$filter=EmployeeID eq {}'.format('EmployeeID,FirstName,LastName', ' or EmployeeID eq '.join(employeeIDs))
url_employees_qry = '{}/Employees?{}'.format(srvc_root, employee_qry)
urldict_employees = make_HTTP_request(url_employees_qry)

dict_customers = {}
dict_employees = {}
dict_orders = {}

for cust in urldict_customers['value']:
    dict_customers[cust['CustomerID']] = cust['CompanyName']

for emp in urldict_employees['value']:
    dict_employees[emp['EmployeeID']] = '{} {}'.format(emp['FirstName'], emp['LastName'])

for order in urldict_orders['value']:
    dict_orders[order['OrderID']] = (dict_customers[order['CustomerID']], dict_employees[order['EmployeeID']])

for orders in sorted(dict_orders.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
    print('{0:7d}  {1:30s}{2:30s}'.format(orders[0], orders[1][0], orders[1][1]))
```

This is the output - the 8 rows (tuples) of 3 columns (attributes) across 3 tables (entities):

```
  10924  Berglunds snabbköp            Janet Leverling               
  10827  Bon app'                      Nancy Davolio                 
  10970  Bólido Comidas preparadas     Anne Dodsworth                
  10816  Great Lakes Food Market       Margaret Peacock              
  10960  HILARION-Abastos              Janet Leverling               
  10927  La corne d'abondance          Margaret Peacock              
  10828  Rancho grande                 Anne Dodsworth                
  10847  Save-a-lot Markets            Margaret Peacock
```

Incidentally, executing on a local PostgreSQL database copy of Northwind, this is the equivalent SQL:

```
SELECT
    O.order_id, C.company_name,
    E.first_name || ' ' || E.last_name AS Employee
FROM
    orders O JOIN employees E ON O.employee_id = E.employee_id
    JOIN customers C ON O.customer_id = C.customer_id
WHERE
    O.order_date > '1998-01-01' AND O.shipped_date > O.required_date
ORDER BY
    C.company_name;
```